# how to send data from webpage to mobile device via SMS

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-development-server

I have just started learning java script and trying to build a small functionality where i have created a form(web page basically) and want to send form data on my mobile device via SMS on the click of submit button.But don't know how to pass data from JS to java class and further how to send it via SMS. Can anyone help me how this can be achieved.
thanks in advance.

Comment: There  may  free  and  pay sms api services you  can  use  on of that  and send data to  mobile.

Comment: You can use `Trello` to send SMS messages.

Comment: @SupunAbesekara thanks for reply..could you please explain little more and suggest few names. and how to use them. what exactly would be required to implement this.

Comment: Html and java can't interact directly.. you might need to use frameworks. Their could be many option I'll suggest go for SPRING-REST tutorial for more info.

Comment: thanks Jay. but can this be implemented through java? and is there any way other than servlet to paas data to java class from JS/HTML code?

Comment: Are you looking for a 3rd party library to do this, or do you simply want submission code that allows you to send an SMS from a web-form? For example Twilio is a mobile communications API I have used with Java and it is very simple, but it is a paid option: https://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: anything lib/code.. that can allow me to send SMS from web from. Actually i don't have clear idea what all options are available to implement this. Hence  looking for any option that can be implemented easily.  Can also go with paid option.. but would prefer the one if not paid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use gsm module and integrate it